# Is there any way by which we can add /system/libs to /data/data/app.com.src.app/lib at installation time?

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I need to add some libs from /system/lib into my app lib folder at runtime. i.e. at /data/data/appName.com.src.appName/lib/.
Is there any way by which we can add libraries from /system/lib/.
can we do it using AndroidManifest.xml?

I am using aapt(from command line) to create apk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way by which we can add libraries from /system/lib/.

Not that I am aware of.

> can we do it using AndroidManifest.xml?

No.

> I need to add some libs from /system/lib into my app lib folder at runtime.

You might consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question where you explain why you "need" this and why you think that it is a good idea.

Comment: Actually I need to add driver specific libs to app. But with each update to driver will change those libs and I need to again change those libs in my app. So this process will get repeat with each driver update.